# Any Android File manager which meets these requirements?

Tags: android, file-management, dark-theme

I am currently looking for an Android File Manager which has following features:

1. Storage analysis (Duplicate file remover, large file indicator etc.)
2. Multimedia support (e.g. built-in image viewer, video & audio player, text editor)
3. Archiving capabilities (packing unpacking zip and other archives)
4. Cloud Storage integration for Mega, OneDrive, G-Drive, Yandex, Dropbox, MediaFire etc.
5. FTP (preferably SMB & LAN too) file transfer via Wi-Fi
6. Root Explorer with hidden & system file support
7. OTG Support
8. Multi-Window (Card UI) support
9. Dark theme

Closest I got is ASUS file manager however it only supports three cloud drives but I have data dispersed across many storage providers. It does not have Root Explorer with hidden & system file support, OTG Support or Multi-Window (Card UI) support.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check out FX File Explorer. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx

It falls short on 1 detail. Please see below for more info.

I will try to answer your questions to the best of my ability.

> Storage analysis (Duplicate file remover, large file indicator etc.)

Yes. It shows storage used both in the file listings and has a separate section for above analysis.

> Multimedia support (e.g. built-in image viewer, video & audio player, text editor)

This is a pro only only feature. I think it is $2.99 to unlock all pro options.

```
Archiving capabilities (packing unpacking zip and other archives)
```

I think this is part of the pro features. It can pack and unpack a bunch of different archives. Zip, tar, 7zip, bzip, etc... are all supported. It can also explore an archive without unpacking it.

```
Cloud Storage integration for Mega, OneDrive, G-Drive, Yandex, Dropbox, MediaFire etc.
```

This is part of the pro features. It currently doesn't support your full list. Just Box, Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive, Owncloud, and SugarSync. However you can add any webdav enabled cloud storage. (Mega should work as a webdav drive.)

```
FTP (preferably SMB & LAN too) file transfer via Wi-Fi
```

This is a pro feature. FTP, SMB, and more are available.

```
Root Explorer with hidden & system file support
```

Yes. Full root support, which can be password protected.

```
OTG Support
```

OTG is supported, depended on your android devices support.

```
Multi-Window (Card UI) support
```

Yes. It allows multi window.

```
Dark theme
```

Fully customizable theming available. Including dark theme and icon theming.

Answer (score 1):

### Try [Mixplorer](https://mixplorer.com).

It fails on the first requirement but all other features you mentioned are fully present. Yeah, all the cloud storage integrations.

From the official site:

```
Easily themable with customization option which lets you select any color you like.
Sort, disable and enable all menu options and action buttons.
Unlimited Tabbed browsing and Dual panel in landscape mode and Drag and Drop between panels also supported.
Easily create Tasks to multitask Copy, Move, ... operations.
Different various View Modes and Sorting Options for each folder separately!
Customizable bookmarks drawer with essential file types already categorized.
Advanced search functions.
Custom USB OTG driver. FAT32 (R/W), exFat(R/W), NTFS (R).
Html viewer which supports MHT, Markdown, AXml, CHM, MAFF and ....
Export/Import all preferences and bookmarks and customized skins.
Packing/unpacking 7z and Zip/Zip64 (splitted-encrypted), TAR, TAR.GZ, TAR.BZ2, GZIP, BZIP2, XZ, WIM, Lizard, LZ4, LZ5, Zstandard.
Unpacking only: AR, ARJ, CAB, CHM, CPIO, CramFS, DMG, EXT, FAT, GPT, HFS, IHEX, ISO, LZH, LZMA, MBR, MSI, NSIS, NTFS, QCOW2, RAR/RAR5, RPM, SquashFS, UDF, UEFI, VDI, VHD, VMDK, XAR and Z.
All your cloud storage needs accessible from one single app. Choose from 19 providers:
Amazon CloudDrive, Mega.co.nz, Mail.ru, Dropbox, Box, Yandex, HiDrive, Baidu, Mediafire, IDrive, Hubic, 4Sync, 4Shared, Google Drive, Meo, OneDrive, OneDrive Business, pCloud, SugarSync, VDisk.
+ clouds which support webdav like (Yandex.ru, OwnCloud, MyDrive.ch, DriveHQ, CloudMe, CloudSafe, ...).
Modifying zip files.
EPub, MobiPacket and PDF reader.
Root access for all advanced operations.
User and System app management with data backup ability for rooted devices.
EncFS volumes supported for all storages.
File encryption and decryption using Aescrypt file format.
FTP/HTTP Server built in + TCP server to receive files from other devices using MiX (Send-to option).
Built-in Image Viewer (it supports GIF, SVG, TGA, ICO,...).
Built-in Media Player + VLC codecs add-on.
Powerful Text Editor.
SAMBA, FTP, SFTP, WEBDAV supported as well.
And many more awesome features for you to explore!
```

### [Files](https://g.co/filesgo)

This app satisfies and only satisfies the first requirement.

I'd suggest use these two apps together, which is my current setup.